# Pyspark Fetch data from database periodically if certain duration has elapsed

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read data from database periodically in Pyspark based on the condition, current_time - lastReadTime > refresh_interval.
The refresh_interval that I have provided is 5min.

It's a structured streaming with Kafka and I join the data coming from postgres later.

However, whenever I change the data in database within 5min, I am getting the new data from database even though 5min has not passed.

Below is the code I am using.

```
def __init__(self, config,spark):
    self.refresh_frequency_sec = config.getint('postgres-config', 'refresh-frequency-sec')
    self.spark = spark
    self.lastMetaReadTime = time()
    self.rules = self.fetchRules()
    
def fetchRules(self):
    jdbcDF = self.spark.read \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")\
        .option("url", self.connection_url) \
        .option("dbtable", self.dbtable) \
        .option("user", self.user) \
        .option("password", self.password) \
        .load()
    return jdbcDF
    
def getRules(self):
    
    if time() - self.lastMetaReadTime > self.refresh_frequency_sec:
        self.rules = self.fetchRules()
        self.lastMetaReadTime = time()
        
    return self.rules
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you caching the `jdbcDF`? If you don't cache the dataframe, spark will reload it every time it is used

Comment: I was caching jdbcDF earlier, but even after the interval is over, jdbcDF didn't get updated with the latest data.

Comment: You haven't shared the code that uses the rules dataframe, but most likely what happens is that your client is using only the `jdbcDF` that was loaded the first time. That is, the method `getRules` is called only once. You can verify this by adding a log inside the method. You can use a different approach, with a background task that periodically unpersists and caches again the `jdbcDF`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong method for 'self.rules' in your **innit**() method.

You innit method should rather be:

```
def __init__(self, config,spark):
    self.refresh_frequency_sec = config.getint('postgres-config', 'refresh-frequency-sec')
    self.spark = spark
    self.lastMetaReadTime = time()
    self.rules = self.getRules()
```